# Pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex: Slice by specific year from DateTime level values

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I want to slice a multi-index pandas dataframe by year to plot annual subsets.

My current approach uses a function that creates a mask to create annual plots in a plotting function:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# dataframe with dates
dates = pd.DataFrame()
dates['2016'] = pd.date_range(start='2016', periods=4, freq='60Min')
dates['2017'] = pd.date_range(start='2017', periods=4, freq='60Min')
dates['2018'] = pd.date_range(start='2018', periods=4, freq='60Min')
dates.reset_index()
dates = dates.unstack()

# multi-indexed dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(36, 3))
df['concept'] = np.repeat(np.repeat(['A', 'B', 'C'], 3), 4)
df['datetime'] = pd.concat([dates, dates, dates], ignore_index=True)
df.set_index(['concept', 'datetime'], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df.info()


# my current approach is to use mask to slice the year
def mask_year(y):
    y = str(y)
    mask = df.index.get_level_values('datetime').year == \
        pd.Timestamp(y).year
    return mask


# plotting using the mask
for yy in np.unique(df.index.get_level_values('datetime').year):
    idx = pd.IndexSlice
    df_plt = df.loc[idx[:, mask_year(yy)], :]
    df_plt = df_plt.groupby(df_plt.index.get_level_values('concept')).sum()
    df_plt.plot(kind="bar", title=yy, stacked=True)
```

But creating mask seems quite circumstancial to me!

I know I can do:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df_slice = df.loc[idx[:, slice(pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'),
                               pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01 03:00:00'))], :]
print(df_slice)
```

which returns the same result as the mask:

```
                                    0         1         2
concept datetime                                         
A       2016-01-01 00:00:00  0.490030  1.190667  0.186234
        2016-01-01 01:00:00 -1.812031 -0.077387 -0.484749
        2016-01-01 02:00:00  0.098846 -0.580555 -0.044958
        2016-01-01 03:00:00 -1.866516 -0.368678 -0.958492
B       2016-01-01 00:00:00 -2.001319 -0.589698  0.072124
        2016-01-01 01:00:00 -0.267139 -1.374081  1.009086
        2016-01-01 02:00:00  0.271937  2.379305  0.134826
        2016-01-01 03:00:00  0.781606  0.181515 -0.922162
C       2016-01-01 00:00:00 -0.333881 -1.050664 -1.839776
        2016-01-01 01:00:00 -0.535254 -0.800394 -0.551664
        2016-01-01 02:00:00  0.410175  0.438866  0.399537
        2016-01-01 03:00:00  0.813004 -1.005976  0.465938
```

But using this approach requires to pass two arguments to the plotting function.

Isn't there any easier way to slice the DateTime level values by year?

Thanks in advance!